# Feedback on Optimizing C# NET Code Block

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, tcp

I just spent quite a few hours reading up on TCP servers and my desired protocol I was trying to implement, and finally got everything working great. I noticed the code looks like absolute bollocks (is the the correct usage? Im not a brit) and would like some feedback on optimizing it, mostly for reuse and readability.

The packet formats are always int, int, int, string, string.

```
try
{
    BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(clientStream);
    int packetsize = reader.ReadInt32();
    int requestid = reader.ReadInt32();
    int serverdata = reader.ReadInt32();
    Console.WriteLine("Packet Size: {0} RequestID: {1} ServerData: {2}", packetsize, requestid, serverdata);

    List<byte> str = new List<byte>();
    byte nextByte = reader.ReadByte();

    while (nextByte != 0)
    {
        str.Add(nextByte);
        nextByte = reader.ReadByte();
    }

    // Password Sent to be Authenticated
    string string1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(str.ToArray());

    str.Clear();
    nextByte = reader.ReadByte();

    while (nextByte != 0)
    {
        str.Add(nextByte);
        nextByte = reader.ReadByte();
    }

    // NULL string
    string string2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(str.ToArray());

    Console.WriteLine("String1: {0} String2: {1}", string1, string2);

    // Reply to Authentication Request
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);

    writer.Write((int)(1)); // Packet Size
    writer.Write((int)(requestid)); // Mirror RequestID if Authenticated, -1 if Failed
    byte[] buffer = stream.ToArray();

    clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    clientStream.Flush();
}
```

I am going to be dealing with other packet types as well that are formatted the same (int/int/int/str/str), but different values. I could probably create a packet class, but this is a bit outside my scope of knowledge for how to apply it to this scenario. If it makes any difference, this is the Protocol I am implementing.

http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_RCON_Protocol

Comment: migrate to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: You may want to check out ProtoBuf (http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/), which lets you do efficient networking without all the plumbing code.

Comment: @Morten - that is a very specific protocol, though; not RCON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that jumps out to me is to always use the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) with any object that implements **IDisposable**.  This will ensure that your objects are properly disposed of even in the event of an exception.

```
private void FillList(BinaryReader reader, List list)
{
    while (reader.PeekChar() != -1)
    {
        list.Add(reader.ReadByte());
    }
}
```

...

```
try
{
    int packetsize, requestid, serverdata;
    string string1, string2;
    List<byte> str = new List<byte>();

    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(clientStream))
    {
        packetsize = reader.ReadInt32();
        requestid = reader.ReadInt32();
        serverdata = reader.ReadInt32();
        Console.WriteLine("Packet Size: {0} RequestID: {1} ServerData: {2}", packetsize, requestid, serverdata);

        FillList(reader, str);

        // Password Sent to be Authenticated
        string1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(str.ToArray());

        str.Clear();
        FillList(reader, str);
    }

    // NULL string
    string2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(str.ToArray());

    Console.WriteLine("String1: {0} String2: {1}", string1, string2);

    // Reply to Authentication Request
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
    {

        writer.Write((int)(1)); // Packet Size
        writer.Write((int)(requestid)); // Mirror RequestID if Authenticated, -1 if Failed
        byte[] buffer = stream.ToArray();

        clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        clientStream.Flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: That is something I have been meaning to look up and didn't. When I was reading on C# I thought it auto disposed itself (I guess it does with using statements) but glad to know to use that now. Do you know if I could extract that while (nextByte != 0) block into its own function? In C++ I could just pass the reader object by reference, but I have no idea how to abstract the function in C#.

Answer (score 3):

Thoughts:

- you arent really using the reader except for a few ints; otherwise, all you need is ReadByte you can do that from the Stream, and save some indirection/confusion
- read the ints manually to avoid Endianness issues
- reading byte by byte can be expensive; if possible, try to fill a buffer (or rather: read the right amount of data) by looping over Read rather that ReadByte
- if multiple messages are coming down the same pipe, reading to EOF will probably fail (either corrupt the data or block forever); you usually need either a terminator sequence or a length-prefix. I prefer the latter, as it let's you use Read instead of ReadByte
- I assume that is packetSize in your example; it is ***critical*** to use this: to separate the messages, to verify you have an *entire* message, and to deny over-sized data
- consider whether async (BeginRead) is suitable - sometimes yes, sometimes no; and note that this makes disposal trickier as you can't use "using" with async
- when using MemoryStream, using .GetBuffer() ***in combination with*** .Length has less overhead than using .ToArray()